# Problemas con operadores lógicos

Tags: php

Tengo dos variables *$socio* y *$mov*.

Según el siguiente detalle traté de armar la secuencia lógica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ambos valores son 0 simplemente sale y **NO HACE NADA**.
Pero si cumple cualquiera de las otras tres combinaciones, primero ejecuta un proceso y luego debe entrar al *if* correspondiente.

```
$socio = 1;
$mov = 1;

if (($socio !== 0) & ($mov !== 0)) {

    // { AQUI VA UN PROCESO QUE DEBE EJECUTARSE ANTES DE LOS IFs

    if (($socio == 0) & ($mov == 1)) {
        echo "ACTUALIZAR ENTRADAS";
        exit;
    }
    if (($socio == 1) & ($mov == 0)) {
        echo "ACTUALIZAR SALIDAS";
        exit;
    }
    if (($socio == 1) & ($mov == 1)) {
        echo "NO ACTUALIZAR";
        exit;
    }
}
echo "NO PROCESAR";
exit;
```

Pero solo funciona cuando ambos valores son 1 (**NO ACTUALIZAR**) o cuando ambos valores son 0 (**NO HACE NADA**).

Cuál es el problema en la lógica?

Comment: En el primer `if` tienes un "and` lo que hace es evaluar únicamente cuando ambas variables don diferentes de 0, si lo que quisieras es que entre al `if` cuando cualquiera de las dos sea `1` entonces necesitas un "or". Por cierto cuando pones únicamente un `&` (and) o un `|` (or) estás haciendo un and/or lógico, no comparando sino que la operación lógica binaria. [Lectura recomendada](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Tal como puse en el comentario, el problema es que en los `if` estás haciendo una operación lógica bit por bit y lo que deberías hacer es utilizar los operadores lógicos.

La diferencia es que por ejemplo al hacer

```
var_dump(1&2)
```

Se compara bit por bit, el 1 en binario es `01` y el 2 en binario es `10`. la operación anterior va a devolver `int(0)` porque se compara el bit con índice `0` de cada número, es decir el que está a la derecha y `1&0` es igual a `0`

Otro problema es que en tu primer `if` únicamente evaluas cuando ambas variables son diferentes de `0` pero lo que debes hacer según lo que expones en la pregunta es evaluar cuando cualquiera es diferente de `0` por lo que necesitas un `or`, no un `and`

Ejemplo completo:

```
$socio = 1;
$mov = 1;

if ($socio || $mov) {

    // { AQUI VA UN PROCESO QUE DEBE EJECUTARSE ANTES DE LOS IFs

    if (($socio == 0) && ($mov == 1)) {
        echo "ACTUALIZAR ENTRADAS";
        exit;
    }
    if (($socio == 1) && ($mov == 0)) {
        echo "ACTUALIZAR SALIDAS";
        exit;
    }
    if (($socio == 1) && ($mov == 1)) {
        echo "NO ACTUALIZAR";
        exit;
    }
}
echo "NO PROCESAR";
```

En la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php) podemos ver que  `and` y `&&` son equivalentes y `or` y `||` también son equivalentes.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero las variables __$socio__ y __$mov__ pueden tener cualquiera de los valores, según la tabla, solo que en el ejemplo puse que tenían en valor 1.

Comment: Así es, pero los problemas de tu código son los mismos que mencioné, ¿Has probado el código que puse con los valores de la tabla para cada variable?

Comment: No me había percado, aunque analizaré bien lo del ||.